# Dateformat in CalenderDatePicker in UWP

Tags: c#, datepicker, uwp

I want custom date format in CalenderDatePicker control , where dateformat is dd-MMM-yyyy in CalenderDatePicker textbox. DateFormat Property supports only 6 formats in CalenderDatePicker control.
I want similar to below described control.

<CalenderDatePicker DateFormat={dd-MMM-yyyy} />

Comment: your question seems incomplete. where is "below described control"?

Comment: @kennyzx please check the question again, the question was incomplete. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<CalendarDatePicker DateFormat="{}{day.integer(2)}-{month.abbreviated}-{year.full}" />
```

Please refer to [DateTimeFormatter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter)